# Php only takes in the first row of the database as correct credentials

Tags: php, authentication

This is the code for my log in forum. The problem with it is that it only accepts as correct credentials the first username and password (basically only the first row) any ideas as to how i could change it ?!

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      include_once("connect.php");
        $token = "";
        if($con->connect_error){
          die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM authme";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

          if(isset($_POST['realname']))


          $username = $_POST['realname'];


        if($result->num_rows>1){






            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>1){


            $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['realname'] = $row['realname'];


            }
            $password = '$SHA$'.substr($row['password'],5,16).'$'.hash('sha256', hash('sha256',$_POST['password']).substr($row['password'],5,16));



            if($password == $row['password'] ){

            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
           }
          else {
            echo "INVALID INFORMATION, PLEASE RETURN!";
        //    header("location: index.php");
            session_destroy();
            exit();
          }
          }

          }
    }
         ?>

?
```

I decided to try to make a log in forum that uses a database which encrypts the passwords it receives through a register form. This code only takes as correct the first username and password i give in and its not enough, as you could imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming with PHP. I'm going to try to share a few principles that may help you solve your problem.

1.) One of the best features in PHP is the print_r() function. Using this function you can output almost anything to text in the browser. So in this case you may want to insert a print_r($result) immediately following this line "$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));". This will output the results of the query that PHP is receiving. This can be used to help you troubleshoot and determine why your code isn't working. Once you're done troubleshooting delete that line.

2.) You seem to have multiple checks for the number of rows inside the while loop. I'm not sure why you have thoose there, but you may want to check if those are causing your trouble by using echo or print to display to values in the browser for troubleshooting. Once you're done troubleshooting delete that line.

3.) Another overall concept for the data you are querying. It is inefficient to send a query that gets the entire table and returns it to the program, that then loops through every row looking for the data. Instead you should write an SQL query to return only the row of data the you want. Make sure you do use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

4.) Your coding standards could use some improvement, if you clearly tabbed your statements it would be easier to read. Consider reading [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). For example this code seems to be missing {}'s.

```
if(isset($_POST['realname']))
$username = $_POST['realname'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Your idea with the prepared statements is interesting, but i dont see how it would help in my case. My idea is I have predefined data in the database. My idea was, for the login form, to go into the database, extract the hashed password which is hashed with a sha256 and subtract a random string from within it and save it into another variable, then construct a new password with it. With that being said, with the new password formed, i was to take that password and compare it with all the other passwords in the database and if it finds a match, to grant access to the forum.